# A simple Variation on the Imaginary Unit i

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, hypercomplex-numbers

I think a more appropriate tag would have been 'quasicomplex numbers' rather than 'hypercomplex numbers'.

I'm normally perfectly comfortable with the correspondence between hyperbolic functions & circular functions - the way one is just the other with imaginary argument, or an imaginary component in the argument ... & all that.

But I ran into a bit of a problem recently with this correspondence seeming to break down. I was looking at a post recently in which the matter of $$\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{atn}(x_k)$$$$=$$$$\operatorname{atn}\left(\frac{\sum _{k\inℕ_0,k<{n\over2}}(-1)^k\operatorname{het}_{n,2k+1}(\underline{x})}{\sum_{k\inℕ_0,k\leq{n\over2}}(-1)^k\operatorname{het}_{n,2k}(\underline{x})}\right)$$with $\operatorname{het}_{n,k}$ denoting the symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables of degree $k$ consisting of the sum of *strictly heterogeneous* products of the variables (I presume this is not standard  notation; but I think it will do here). Another contibutor exposited that this is a consequence of the fact that $\operatorname{atn}x$ is the argument of $1+ix$ together with the fact that the argument of the product of a set of complex numbers is the sum of the arguments: and indeed if you expand$$\prod_{k=1}^n(1+ix_k)$$you get those symmetric polynomials, and the tangent of the argument is indeed the function of the $x_j$ constituting the *content* (it's getting awkward through 'argument' having two different meanings here!) of $\operatorname{atn}$ on the RHS of the relation shown above.

But you also have$$\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{atnh}(x_k)$$$$=$$$$\operatorname{atnh}\left(\frac{\sum _{k\inℕ_0,k<{n\over2}}\operatorname{het}_{n,2k+1}(\underline{x})}{\sum_{k\inℕ_0,k\leq{n\over2}}\operatorname{het}_{n,2k}(\underline{x})}\right) ,$$ and yet there is no corresponding logic for this ... *unless ... perhaps* you introduce an operator (let's call it $h$ for now) that has the properties $h≠1$, $|h|=1$, & $h^2=1$. The entity $h$ is *not* 1 ... and yet $h^2$ *does* (coz it *does **right!!?***) = 1 ... $h$ is just *eheieh asher eheieh* - it just *is what it is*. (I've found that this point can be *such a stumblingblock* for people who are learning these things - the idea of an entity just being *what it is* ... & also how my own mind kept reverting to *wanting* some explicit statement in terms of $\pi$, or decimals, or whatever, of what $i$ *is* ... & how one day it just 'clicked' that it's not *occasioned* - and indeed there *is none*!)

And then you could have precisely analogous logic for the formula for the sum of plural $\operatorname{atanh}$, with the 'argument' of$$\prod_{k=1}^n(1+hx_k)$$ analogous to the argument of the *circular* complex product above.

The question is, is there any occurence of such ... *hyperbolically complex numbers* in mathematics *atall*; and has the idea ever been developed atall? I think if you were to put any kind of *interpretation* on the 'meaning' of this $h$, it would be that whereas $i$ is a *rotation*, $h$ is a *reflection*. And we are of course free to define any entity we wish ... the chief question then is "is the entity we have defined just a total *cul-de-sac*, or is there some mileage in it?" Maybe there is *no* mileage in this $h$ beyond it's being an expedient for *buttressing* the analogy between circular & hyperbolic functions.

Another entity we could define, for instance, and which in effect kind of *is* defined in the differential calculus would be (let's call it) $\epsilon$, which has the rather mutually-strange properties $\epsilon≠0$, $|\epsilon|=0$,  & $\epsilon^2=0$.

Comment: You mean, has someone developed the the theory of functions of a split-complex number? People have done so since the mid-19th century:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number#History

Comment: @K B Dave -- Right! Lets have a look at this then.

Comment: Your $h$ is often denoted $j$, but it can be $h$ too, and $\epsilon$ is standard for what it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number

Comment: @K B Dave -- just had a scan of it ... it looks like what I'm after. _And_ moreover, I've noticed that there's mention of it in connection with the  _rapidity_ of special relativity, which has _particularly_ piqued my attention, as I remember many years ago trying to get to grips with that subject, & it occuring to me that these _split_ numbers could be applied ... but abandoning it, telling myself I'd gotten snared by some flaky fantasy & that I was overtired. So I'm very much looking forward to searching this out properly. Thanks for that direction. It's pity that so much oldstuff neglected!

Comment: @J G -- Dual number _also_! I was just comnenting to K B Dave, but ran out of space, how it's a pity that there is _loads_ of this curious stuff out there that has just _fallen away_ somehow over the years. I certainly think I can count this a successful post now; & I'm looking forward to checking out _your_ directions also, for which I tender my thanks ¶ However, people will get used to this - I'm not a fan of _voting systems_ on webfora in general _atall atall_ and I'll be confining my feedback to comments ... especially as you can only vote for _one_ & answers often different anyway as here

Comment: @Ambrette: this stuff hasn't "fallen away" at all, it's just all been subsumed into ring theory.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan -- Hmmm ... but 'fallen away' still, I think, in that that's _where it stays_ for the most part! It just doesn't seem to have any _threads spun-out_ from it involved in other _departnents_!.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, these things exist and are called the [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) $\mathbb{R}[j]/(j^2 - 1)$. They are just another example of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory), albeit a funny example because they aren't an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) and so some familiar properties of rings like the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ don't apply: for example, as you've observed, in the split complex numbers the equation $x^2 = 1$ has four solutions $1, -1, j, -j$, more than its degree.

In the same way as the complex numbers can be thought of in terms of $2 \times 2$ [matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) via the correspondence

$$a + bi \leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & - b \\ b & a \end{array} \right]$$

the split-complex numbers can also be thought of in terms of $2 \times 2$ matrices via the correspondence

$$a + bj \leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ b & a \end{array} \right].$$

What this reveals is that, just as you wrote, in the same way that $i$ represents a rotation, $j$ represents a reflection.

Abstractly the split-complex numbers are [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) as a ring to the product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ of two copies of the real numbers, via the correspondence

$$a + bj \leftrightarrow (a + b, a - b)$$

and so they aren't genuinely "new" in the same way that the complex numbers are. But again, as you say, they are a cute way of expressing the analogy between hyperbolic and trigonometric functions. For example there is a hyperbolic [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

$$\exp(j t) = \cosh t + j \sinh t.$$

The [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) $\mathbb{R}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ as you mention, and as mentioned in the comments, are another example of a ring, and find some use. There are lots more rings than this, though. If you really want to have some fun you can learn about the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) next.

Comment: _A ring that isn't an integral domain_! Well that's something in its own right - and equations having a number of solutions greater than the degree - that is _weird_! Abd it makes me wonder just how far this matter has been developed. ¶ And speeaking more generally, there _does_ seem to be a certain _duality_ between 'circular' space or _hypobolic_ space, & _hyperbolic_ space, (space of _functions_, thatis) we could say: there is also the _perfect_ of a matrix - like determinant, but with no 'checkerboard of signs - much less well -known ... but I have seen aoplications of it here & there.

Comment: @Ambrette: ring theory is extremely well-developed in many different directions. There are lots of different branches to it with emphasis on different kinds of rings depending on what you want to do with them. My first exposure to it was through number theory and rings like the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which can be used to prove lots of fun facts like that every prime congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ is a sum of two squares (of integers).

Comment: It is, like _surpassingly amazing_, group theory, ring theory, field theory, & all that. In a sense it is the theory of _relation __per se___ - not the relations of _any particular things_ ... but just ... _relation_, in-&-of itself. And it never ceases to baffle me that _sheer relation_ gives-rise to so many _particular patterns_: the particular groups that can exist of a given order; and the particular _anatomies_ of those groups in terms of their _subgroups_ & _conjugacy classes_, & the various other kinds of _internal organ_ that they have.

Comment: _Not_ the _perfect_ of a matrix - that that's like the determinant but without the 'checkerboard' of signs, but rather - the _permanent_!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey tessarines (split-complex+complex numbers) have (accounting for multiplicity) $n^2$ roots of an equation of degree $n$. There is nothing weird with it, a quadratic equation has no more than 4 roots.

Comment: I wonder, why you said their isomorphism the pairs of real numbers makes them not interesting. Do they correspond to those pairs with element-by-element operations?

Comment: By the way, this actually means that split-complex numbers represent *intervals* of real numbers, and maybe isomorphic to interval arithmetic? Also, this fact explains, why the sign function on split-complex numbers has 9 possible values, and not infinity as in complex numbers and as intuitively expected... If the both ends of an interval are positive, the number is positive, etc, overall (including zero), 9 options. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407872/is-the-number-of-values-the-sign-function-can-take-on-a-ring-signedness-of-a